# ReferenceError: Error #1065: Переменная Main не определена.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

При подключений библиотек .swc quickbox2d вылетает такая ошибка **ReferenceError: Error #1065: Переменная Main не определена**. кто встречался подскажите как исправить?

**Добавлено.**

```
package 
{
    import As3Math.geo2d.*;
    import flash.display.*;
    import QuickB2.objects.tangibles.*;
    import QuickB2.stock.*;

    /** Really simple example that pulls in the precompiled QuickB2.swc.
     * 
     * @author Doug Koellmer
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            var world:qb2World = qb2Stock.newDebugWorld(new amVector2d(0, 10), this.graphics, stage);
            world.start();

            var circle:qb2CircleShape = qb2Stock.newCircleShape(new amPoint2d(100, 100), 50, 1);
            world.addObject(circle);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может такой класс есть в quickbox2d? Хотя очень странное именование, еще более странное для переменной. Нужен кусок кода.

Comment: можешь сам скачать посмотреть http://code.google.com/p/quickb2/downloads/detail?name=QuickB2_0_6.zip там и пример Hello World

Comment: скачал, запустил во Flash Builder, компилит и запускает

Comment: не знаю, но это не нужно, по вышей ссылке есть исходники этого движка

попытался пример открыть в Flash CS5 - ничего не выходит, если с нуля туда вставлять, в отдельный не документный класс или метод, то все проходит

Comment: Я не как не могу откомпилить не чего связаного с swc. вот тут взял    http://code.google.com/p/nape/wiki/Downloads?tm=2 физический движок nape f тут пример http://www.deltaluca.me.uk/doc/swf/Decomposition%20Demo.html таже самая ошибка

Comment: Я вообще не чего не могу понять сейчас скачал библиотеку для 9 flash player и 10. 9 идет на 10 такая же ошибка как и раньше.

Comment: по последней ссылке псевдо-код, просто для понимания

вам нужно посидеть почитать, как собирается проект в cs4, где пишется код

по большому счету, нужно ориентироваться на flash builder, большие проекты на flash ide это очень сурово, это дизайнерская прога

Comment: установил cs5 все заработало